# UITableView with NSFetchedResultsController reloadData but does not move cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsnotificationcenter

I have a UITableView backed with an NSFetchedResultsController.

When the controller goes off screen I follow suggestion to resign as fetched controller delegate.
Therefore I totally rely on context notification and reloadData.

Basically, I analyze the notification and set a flag needsReload=YES when in the inserted/updated/deleted object there's a relevant entity and property for the table.
On viewWillAppear I check for this variable and call reloadData.

However the NSFetchedResultsController has an sort ordering on NSManagedObject attribute 'pname'.

When in other view controller I update pname say from 0name to Zname, I can intercept the context did change notification and the table is correctly reloaded at next viewWillAppear.

The problem is that I would expect the cell to goes at bottom because of the sort ordering, but instead it remains updated at top, I suppose because reloadData only updates visible cell. How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fetched results controller does not track changes in the managed object context anymore if you set its delegate to `nil`.

Therefore, after re-assigning a delegate, you have to call

```
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]
```

first and then

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have to reissue the fetch then. What about performance issues, especially with large row set. And also, what do you think of resigning delegate when off screen. I heard many people suggesting this, but none had really documented this choice.

Comment: @Leonardo: I do not have a definite answer for that. I would recommend to test both variants and profile with Instruments. It probably depends on the number of changes compared to the size of the row set.